# MySQL SUBSTR LOCATE multi-search-strings

Tags: mysql, replace, substring, substr, locate

Tricky one, and my brain is mush after staring at my screen for about an hour.

I'm trying to query my database to return the first part of a string (domain name eg. `http://www.example.com`) in the column `image_link`.

I have managed this for all rows where the `image_link` contains `.com` as part of the string... but I need the code to be more versatile, so it searches for the likes of `.net` and `.co.uk` too.

Had thought some sort of nested `REPLACE` might work, but it doesn't make sense when I try to apply it - and I'm stuck.

Query Builder code:

```
$builder->select("SUBSTRING(image_link, 1, LOCATE('.com', image_link) + 3) AS domain");
```

Example strings, with desired results:

```
http://www.example.com/brands/567.jpg // http://www.example.com
https://www.example.org/photo.png     // https://www.example.org
http://example.net/789                // http://example.net
```

Any help/advice warmly welcomed!

Comment: Can you provide several inputs along with what the exact output you want is here?

Comment: [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) amended thanks!

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) Version information: 4.9.7

Comment: Is that your client version or the MySQL version?  Please run this query: `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1)`.  Does it execute without error?

Comment: [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) You're right, that's phpMyAdmin version. I can't get that code to run

Comment: There is a regex based solution, but that would require MySQL 8+ version.  Without regex, there won't be much you can do here.

Comment: [@Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) Fingers crossed! Can you direct me to an example of it, and I'll try and figure it out.

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url ... again, you'll need MySQL 8+ to do this.

Comment: [@TimBiegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) Well, that was a fail! Discovered I'm running MySQL Version 5.7. Little bit out of date! Lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ... , 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_link, '/', 3) domain
FROM test;
```

Or, if protocol may be absent, then

```
SELECT ... , 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(image_link, '/', CASE WHEN LOCATE('//', image_link) THEN 3 ELSE 1 END) domain
FROM test;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d42238593bcbca2ab4c6c66c2015244e)